# when to use form facade in in laravel?

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, laravel-5, facade

I am fairly new to laravel. I am learning it's various components gradually. I was going through one of the tutorials where I found 'Form and Html Facade'. I understand that it automates a few lines of code for us and makes the process faster but does it offer any other advantage apart from this?

Also, I saw we could direct the form to some specific method of a controller on submission. Can we do the same without using a facade too? If yes, please show an example , so that I may follow.

Actually, I have a web-designer's background and I am much more comfortable coding in raw HTML and CSS . So, If I am sure about not missing out some great laravel-tool, I can happily continue with raw HTML codes.

Comment: Generally I don't like using form facade. I prefer raw HTML. Form facade has be removed from laravel core in laravel 5 because its just a helper class. By using HTML you have more control on your tags and can be reusable in a case for instance when you wish to insert Angularjs tags or directives

Comment: Please note that your question is opinion based very soon someone will close it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I share the same opinion about facade as yours. But, should I be concerned about not using it? I mean, would I miss something if I don't use it. Specifically, it would be helpful if you can answer the second para of my question.

Comment: Not at all. Most Laravel developers don't use it. So if you are not lazy don't use it. Nothing to miss out

Comment: Its okay. Build something awesome